# Can you apply for UK Tier IV visa from outside your home country?

Tags: usa, united-kingdom, visa, uk-visa, covid-19

I'm trying to apply for a UK tier IV visa to start on a PhD course starting in October. While the UKVI office is taking applications, there are no visa application centers open (or any date given to reopen) in the US to collect biometric data. So, I have two questions:

1. Can the visa office use previous biometric data for a new residence card?
2. Is it possible to apply for a Tier IV visa outside of your home country while on a visitor visa to another country?

Comment: Do you mean a Tier 4 visa? I've never seen it referred to as "Tier IV" before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to both your questions is unfortunately, no. For UK visas, it is required biometrics are taken for each application. There is, as of yet, no relaxation of this requirement.

And Tier 4 visas [are not one of the categories of visa](https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/where-to-apply-ecb05/ecb5-where-to-apply-the-policy) which can be applied from outside a country you are resident in.

However, in your situation, I would be cautiously optimistic that a solution will be found in time for the beginning of the next academic year. UKVI are certainly aware of the importance of getting the process up and running before then.